# To get + adjective/V3

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-choice

The past simple and present perfect form of "I am dirty" and "I become dirty" are:

```
"I was dirty"
"I have been dirty"
"I became dirty"
"I have become dirty"
```

What is the present perfect form of "I get dirty"? Do you natives ever use the present perfect form of "to get + adjective/past participle"?
I know the past simple form would be "I got dirty".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Present_perfect):

> In modern English, the auxiliary verb used to form the present perfect is always *to have*. A typical present perfect clause thus consists of the subject, the auxiliary *have/has*, and the past participle (third form) of main verb. Examples:
>
> I **have done** so much in my life.
>         You **have gone** to school.
>         He **has** already **arrived** in America.
>         He **has had** child after child... (The Mask of Anarchy, Percy Shelley)
>         Lovely tales that **we have heard or read**... (Endymion, John Keats)

As such, the present perfect tense of *I get dirty* is the following:

> I **have got** dirty.

---

Comparing *I got dirty*, *I became dirty*, and *I have got dirty*, [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%20got%20dirty%2CI%20have%20got%20dirty%2CI%20became%20dirty&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20got%20dirty%3B%2Cc0) shows that, at least in print, only *I got dirty* is commonly used:

[image: I got dirty versus I became dirty versus I have got dirty]

Although I, too, would personally use *I got dirty* over the other forms, the other forms are still understandable and I would not find them that strange if used by somebody else—especially if used in the context of other phrases that also used those tenses.

For example:

> "Honey, **I've got** your flowers from the garden. Unfortunately, **I've** also **got** dirty."

At least to me, when used in conjunction with another phrase that also uses the present perfect, it makes it sound more natural in context. (And, to some degree, at least in this example, it also sounds a bit like a humorous play on words.)

Comment: I can't think of a sentence where someone would say "I have got dirty" in the sense of the present. Would we actually use that in English (other than to mean, say, "I have/I've got dirty shoes in the washbin")?

Comment: @Danneyland I updated my answer to provide an example of the kind of parallel structure I'd mentioned would make it sound more natural in context.

Comment: Are sentences "I don't want to hug you because I got dirty" and "I don't want to hug you because I have got dirty" correct?

Comment: @Vova They are both grammatical, yes. However, I'd say that the most natural phrasing would be *I don't want to hug you because I **am** dirty*.

Comment: Thank you all very much!